How to use zoom in out, touches in WebView inside a ScrollView in React Native
Hi I am using WebView to render my candlestick chart in React Native but I am stuck in the zoom in/out touches of WebView if I put it inside a ScrollView
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export function TradeTabCharts() {
  return (
    <ScrollView scrollEnabled style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 300}}></View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 500 }}>
                <WebView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    source={{ uri: 'https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?type=spot' }}
                    nestedScrollEnabled
                    originWhitelist={['*']}
                    overScrollMode="never"
                    mixedContentMode="always"
                    scalesPageToFit
                    javaScriptEnabled
                    domStorageEnabled
                    thirdPartyCookiesEnabled
                    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 300}}></View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 300}}></View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

I can scroll the website very good just when I am using the chart functions like zooming or horizontal scrolling the chart will does not work properly. then I just need 1 fingers to zoom in out instead of two fingers...
Thanks for your help. I was stucked there for 2 days :(

Fixed it due to react-native-gesture-handler
I changed to ScrollView of react-native then everything work well
